# Severity 14 error state 16 on our SQL Server 2005 ,login failed for user 'username'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, iis-6

We had the problem with

source:

> *logon error:18456,severity:14, state 16
>
>   login failed for user 'user name' client [XXXX]*

`XXXX`: is our IP address on our SQL Server 2005 machine.

The important points are

1. The error came and gone by itself
2. That to for only one database
3. Mainly occurs at night (7pm-8am)
4. Above error is very very less in day time (8am-6pm)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:ii6] and [tag:c#-2.0]? Also, what is your question?!

Comment: because above error is occurs in SQL server log
but for clients the error will look like this
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "db" requested by the login.so i tagged in C# 2.0 
The login failed.
Login failed for user 'user'.

Comment: Understanding "login failed" http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx

Comment: @Igor, it's all about the `State`, and there's no `State 16` in that link. Early indications show me that `State 16` is an old, generic message, meaning the db couldn't be opened. Either the user lacks permissions or the server is inaccessible: https://sqlblog.org/2020/07/28/troubleshooting-error-18456

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this in the past.  After researching around we found that this was due to the user not having permission to login to the database that has been setup as their default.  It was a newly setup DB user for use by SSIS imports.

We used [ALTER LOGIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189828.aspx) to resolve the issue.

```
ALTER LOGIN [username]
WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = [database name]
```

Note: This was using SQL Server 2008 but it should be the same for 2005.

Comment: Note I forgot specify that you should set the user's default DB to one that they *do* have access to login to.

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for all your replies. I finally found a permanent solution for this in our application.

#### Reasons

1. this was due to the user not having permission to login to the database that has been setup as their default.
2. the DB Sometimes goes to In Recovery, for that time that particular DB not available for users.
3. At the same time in SQL error log we can find Starting up Database 'DB'

#### Solution

Go your Microsoft SSMS,select that db->Properties->Options-> there if Auto Close is set to true ,Alter Auto Close to false and Click Ok.
It will solve it permanently.